# Can I know which triangle I am working on from within the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I'm drawing a medium-to-large object with somewhere between 100 and maybe 2500 triangular faces, depending on some options the user picked earlier. The object itself is fixed-- doesn't move, doesn't undergo any transformations, nothing. You could think of things, so far, as "my app loads OBJ files, and then the user looks at them," and you wouldn't be far wrong.

The tricky bit is that at any time, some of the faces on the object will be "selected", and some won't. The selected faces have to display with a different texture-- same UV coordinates, but with the pixel color coming from a different bitmap. About half of the faces will be selected at any given time, and which ones will change continually.

So, the obvious thing to do is, within the fragment shader, if I'm working on a selected face, call texture2D() on THIS bitmap, and if I'm in a not-selected triangle, use THAT one. Only, I don't see a way to find out which triangle I'm in from the fragment shader. Which is my question: can I know this?

I do have an alternative-- set up every face with its own copy of the vertices, double the size of the texture bitmap, set up the UV coordinates on the per-face vertices to point to the "selected" or "deselected" part of the bitmap-- but the number of vertices goes up 6x, and I'm passing an entire new array of UV's to the GPU every single frame, and... yeah. Noticeably slow, even on smallish objects. Not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment shader does not know about which triangle it is in. However, can get the effect you want by using an extra vertex attribute.

Unluckily, this usually means that you have to duplicate vertex data per triangle in the same way as you have to do when doing hard creases -- there is no easy way of doing it differently, at least not when it has to work with *any* kind of selection.
However, using separate streams, you really only need to upload that one attribute every frame, the rest is constant. Insofar, it is quite acceptable bandwidth-wise.

The fragment shader would then statically sample both textures and choose one or the other value based on whether the special vertex attribute is 1.0 or 0.0 (this is more efficient than branching and sampling a different texture every time, which will likely sample both textures anyway). You could use the `mix` intrinsic for this (which usually results in a single native 1-cycle instruction), or the ternary operator.

A kind-of-working alternative for some subsets of selections that does not require you to duplicate vertex data would be to use a step function on the attribute cutting off at 1.0 -- the problem which requires vertex duplication being interpolation.
If any single vertex attribute is zero, then the interpolated value at any fragment (other than a fragment exactly under a vertex with "1.0") will necessarily be less than 1.0. On the other hand, any fragments other than the ones under "0.0" vertices or exactly on the line between two "0.0" vertices will be non-zero. This does not work for *every arbitrary* selection, but for many cases, using a strategy such as "anything non-zero is selected" (or the other way around) may work, without duplicating vertex data.

Having ARB_provoking_vertex would ease your life, but alas... no ES 2.0 implementation will likely provide that.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer. Using an extra vertex attribute instead of the UV coordinates will considerably reduce the amount of stuff I have to copy down to the GPU per frame, at least.